# Aborting the loop using external events

Tags: evaluation, kernel, abort

If we run one Wolfram Kernel (Wolfram Engine) there is one thread we can use

```mathematica
While[True,
   doSmth;
   Pause[0.1];
];
```

since there is a sort of interruption mechanism `ScheduledTask`

```
SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[Print["Hello!"], {10}]];

While[True,
   doSmth;
   Pause[0.1];
];
```

so it can interrupt the main loop in 10 seconds after the start, no matter what happens inside `doSmth`. My question is: can we go further and control the loop using `ScheduledTask` or `SocketListener`?

**How can we `Abort` something running inside `While`?**

For example the `master` kernel sends the command to abort the running program inside the `secondary kernel`

```mathematica
(*some master kernel*)

WriteString[kernelsocket, "Abort[]"]
```

```mathematica
(*some secondary kernel*)
SocketListener[message_] := ToExpression[message];
```

Comment: There might be solution using Link[] to call other kernel or using RunProcess[], where you can actually send CTRL-C and choose interrupt. But feels too expensive, compared to possible `try catch` construction like to control the evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as always there is some tricky undocumented way how to do that.
Apart from that, there are some limitations

1. No, you can't control your own loops or handlers in such a way
2. You need a separate kernel to control something
3. WSTP is a only way, how to do `Abort`s on a secondary kernel, without ruining  you background tasks
4. Use `LinkWrite` and `LinkInterrupt` (with undocumented flag 3)

Here is an example

```
link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -wstp"];
LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[(*Any kind of a heavy code*)]];
```

to abort, use

```
LinkInterrupt[link, 3];

(*for some reasons, you need to write something to finish the abortion*)
LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated[$Aborted] ];
```